# What's the difference between facet_wrap() and facet_grid() in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I've been reading the `ggplot2` documentation for both functions. I was wondering what were the differences and what would be right situation for using each function (`facet_wrap()` and `facet_grid()`).

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- qplot(displ, hwy, data = mpg)
p + facet_wrap(~ cyl)

p + facet_grid(~ cyl)
```

I provide this small example to serve as starting point. The difference seems to be wrap makes the plots more autonomous and grid makes one plot all together.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The answer below refers to the case when you have 2 arguments in `facet_grid()` or `facet_wrap()`.

`facet_grid(x ~ y)` will display `x*y` plots even if some plots are empty.
Ex:

```
library(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy))
```

There are 4 distinct cyl and 7 distinct class values.

```
g + geom_point(alpha=1/3) + facet_grid(cyl~class)
```

The above displays 4 * 7 = 28 plots, even if some are empty (because some classes do not have corresponding cylinder values, like rows with class="midsize" doesn't have any corresponding cyl="5" value )
`facet_wrap(x ~ y)` on the other hand, displays only the plots having actual values.

```
g + geom_point(alpha=1/3) + facet_wrap(cyl~class)
```

There are 19 plots displayed now, one for every combination of cyl and class.

Answer (score 24):

`facet_wrap(...)` strings together `ggplots` in different frames (facets) based in a single variable. `facet_grid(...)` can take two variables:

```
p + facet_grid(cyl~class)
```

You can also use a third variable to group in each facet:

```
qplot(displ, hwy, data=mpg,color=factor(year)) + facet_grid(cyl~class)
```

shows the improvement (or lack thereof) in hwy mileage vs. displacement by #cylinders and class.

Comment: `facet_wrap` can take two variables also.

Answer (score 23):

Quoting mainly from ggplot2 book, p. 148f., online version: https://ggplot2-book.org/facet.html

There are three types of facetting:

- `facet_null()` : a single plot, the default.
- `facet_wrap()` : "wraps" a 1d ribbon of panels into 2d.
- `facet_grid()` : produces a 2d grid of panels defined by variables which form
  the rows and columns.

[image]

**Facet wrap**

`facet_wrap()` makes a long ribbon of panels (generated by any number of
variables) and wraps it into 2d. This is useful if you have a single variable
with many levels and want to arrange the plots in a more space efficient
manner.

You can control how the ribbon is wrapped into a grid with `ncol`, `nrow`,
`as.table` and `dir`. `ncol` and `nrow` control how many columns and rows (you only need to set one). `as.table` controls whether the facets are laid out like
a table (`TRUE`), with highest values at the bottom-right, or a plot (`FALSE`),
with the highest values at the top-right. `dir` controls the direction of wrap:
**h**orizontal or **v**ertical.

**Facet grid**

From `?facet_grid` : `facet_grid()` forms a matrix of panels defined by row and column faceting variables. It is most useful when you have two discrete variables, and all combinations of the variables exist in the data.

You can use multiple variables in the rows or columns, by "adding" them
together, e.g. `a + b ~ c + d`.

`facet grid()` has an additional parameter called `space`, which takes the
same values as `scales`.

```
# If scales and space are free, then the mapping between position
# and values in the data will be the same across all panels. This
# is particularly useful for categorical axes
ggplot(subset(mpg, manufacturer %in% c("audi", "honda", "toyota")) , aes(drv, model)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_grid(manufacturer ~ ., scales = "free", space = "free") +
    theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0))
```

[image]

( simplified ) Example taken from `?facet_grid`

Answer (score 11):

For single variable plots you can use either `facet_grid()` or `facet_wrap()`.

`facet_wrap(~variable)` will return a symmetrical matrix of plots for the number of levels of `variable`.

`facet_grid(.~variable)` will return facets equal to the levels of `variable` distributed horizontally.

`facet_grid(variable~.)` will return facets equal to the levels of `variable` distributed vertically.

Comment: Do u know why it is `facet_wrap(~variable)` and not `facet_wrap(variable~)`?