# Default panel layout of ggplot2::facet_wrap()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I'm trying to understand the default behavior of `ggplot2::facet_wrap()`, in terms of how the panel layout is decided as the number of facets increases.

I've read the `?facet_wrap` help file, and also googled this topic with limited success. In one [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457905/whats-the-difference-between-facet-wrap-and-facet-grid-in-ggplot2), `facet_wrap()` was said to "return a symmetrical matrix of plots", but I did not find anything that explained what exactly the default behavior would be.

So next I made a series of plots which had increasing numbers of facets (code shown further down).

[image: Set of plots with increasing number of facets]

The pattern in the image makes it seem like `facet_wrap()` tries to "make a square"...

**Questions**

1. Is that correct? Does `facet_wrap` try to render the facet
   panels so in totality they are most like a square, in terms of the
   number of elements in the rows and columns?
2. If not, what is it actually doing? Do graphical parameters factor in?

**Code that made the plot**

```
# load libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

# plotting function
facetPlots <- function(facets, groups = 8){
   # sample data  
   df <- data.frame(Group = sample(LETTERS[1:groups], 1000, replace = T),
                    Value = sample(1:10000, 1000, replace = T),
                    Facet = factor(sample(1:facets, 1000, replace = T)))
   # get means
   df <- aggregate(list(Value = df$Value), 
                   list(Group = df$Group, Facet = df$Facet), mean)

   # plot
   p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x= Group, y= Value, fill = Group))+
           geom_bar(stat="identity", show.legend = FALSE)+
           facet_wrap(. ~ Facet) +
           theme_bw()+
     theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 6, 
        margin = margin(.1, 0, .1, 0, "cm")),
       axis.text.x=element_blank(),
       axis.ticks=element_blank(),
       axis.title.x=element_blank(),
       axis.text.y=element_blank(),
       axis.title.y=element_blank(),
       plot.margin = unit(c(3,3,3,3), "pt"))
  p1

}

# apply function to list
plot_list <- lapply(c(1:25), facetPlots)
# unify into single plot
plot <- ggpubr::ggarrange(plotlist = plot_list)
```

Comment: Without looking at the ggplot code, I wouldn't be surprised if it used something like `grDevices::n2mfrow` as a default (although it seems for some plots it switches from row rather than column)

Comment: ... perhaps https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/660aad2db2b3495ae0d8040915a40d247133ffc0/R/facet-wrap.r#L453

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how the default number of rows and columns are calculated:

```
ncol <- ceiling(sqrt(n))
nrow <- ceiling(n/ncol)
```

Apparently, `facet_wrap` tends to prefer wider grids, since "*most displays are roughly rectangular*" (according to the documentation). Hence, the number of columns would be greater than or equal to the number of rows.

For your example:

```
n <- c(1:25)

ncol <- ceiling(sqrt(n))
nrow <- ceiling(n/ncol)

data.frame(n, ncol, nrow)
```

Here are the computed numbers of rows/cols:

```
#   n   ncol   nrow
#   1      1      1
#   2      2      1
#   3      2      2
#   4      2      2
#   5      3      2
#   6      3      2
#   7      3      3
#   8      3      3
#   9      3      3
#  10      4      3
#  11      4      3
#  12      4      3
#  13      4      4
#  14      4      4
#  15      4      4
#  16      4      4
#  17      5      4
#  18      5      4
#  19      5      4
#  20      5      4
#  21      5      5
#  22      5      5
#  23      5      5
#  24      5      5
#  25      5      5
```

Comment: As mentioned by @user20650, it could be using  `grDevices::n2mfrow`. The only exception might be when n==3. It's actually 3x1 rather than 2x2