# Reproducing ggplot2's facet_wrap plot with alternative functions

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, facet-wrap, gridextra

I have a `data.frame` that I'd like to produce bar plots for with `ggplot2`'s `geom_bar`, faceted by one of the columns in the `data.frame` - `cluster`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(cluster = c("c1","c1","c1","c2","c2","c2","c3","c3","c3"), group = rep(c("A","B","C"),3), p = c(0.4,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.2,0.3,0.5))
```

It's clear how to produce this with `ggplot2`'s `facet_wrap`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = p, group = cluster, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  scale_x_discrete(name = NULL,labels = levels(df$group), breaks = sort(unique(df$group))) +
  facet_wrap(as.formula("~ cluster")) + theme_minimal() + theme(legend.title = element_blank()) + ylab("Fraction of cells")
```

But for reasons that are not mentioned in this post (not very relevant) `facet_wrap` doesn't work for me and I need to resort to producing a list of plots, one for each cluster, and arrange them myself in a grid:

```
plot.list <- lapply(unique(df$cluster),function(l){
  ggplot(dplyr::filter(df,cluster == l), aes(x = group, y = p, fill = group)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
    scale_x_discrete(name = NULL,labels = levels(dplyr::filter(df,cluster == l)$group), breaks = sort(unique(dplyr::filter(df,cluster == l)$group))) +
    theme_minimal() + theme(legend.title = element_blank(), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + ylab("Fraction of cells") + ggtitle(l)
})
```

There are two benefits of `facet_wrap` that I'm missing by not using it that I'm trying to find out how to retain:

1. Automatically deciding on the dimensions of the grid layout: any idea how `facet_wrap` does that and perhaps if that information can be extracted from running the plotting that's using `facet_wrap` command above?
2. `facet_wrap` also automatically shares the axis titles and ticks, but `gridExtra::grid.arrange` or `scater::multiplot` do not. The only way to achieve that with these functions is to suppress these `themes` for all the clusters in the `lapply` call which the user does not want to come out with these labels (imitating `facet_wrap`). I guess that an answer for question 1 offers an answer to this question (conditioning axis label suppression on the location of the cluster in the desired grid), but if anyone has a more direct solution that'll be great.

In other and simple words, I'm looking for a generic way to reproduce the plot grid using `facet_wrap` above with `gridExtra::grid.arrange` or `scater::multiplot` (or any other function) applied to `plot.list`

Comment: The grid layout will be determined by the function `grDevices::n2mfrow(number_of_clusters)`. Have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60104268/default-panel-layout-of-ggplot2facet-wrap or the github page mentioned  in the post: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/660aad2db2b3495ae0d8040915a40d247133ffc0/R/facet-wrap.r#L453

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimensions of the facet_wrap plot can be found in the wrap_dims function.

```
x=ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = p, group = cluster, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  scale_x_discrete(name = NULL,labels = levels(df$group), breaks = sort(unique(df$group))) +
  facet_wrap(as.formula("~ cluster")) + theme_minimal() + theme(legend.title = element_blank()) + ylab("Fraction of cells")
col=wrap_dims(length(x))[2]

plot.list=list()
for (i in 1:length(unique(df$cluster))) {
  y=ggplot(dplyr::filter(df,cluster == unique(df$cluster)[i]), aes(x = group, y = p, fill = group)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
    scale_x_discrete(name = NULL,labels = levels(dplyr::filter(df,cluster == unique(df$cluster)[i])$group), breaks = sort(unique(dplyr::filter(df,cluster == unique(df$cluster)[i])$group))) +
    theme_minimal() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + ggtitle(unique(df$cluster)) + ylim(0, max(df$p))
  if (i<length(unique(df$cluster))) {
    y=y+theme(legend.position="none")
  }
  if (i>1) {
    y=y+ylab("")
  } else {
    y=y+ylab("Fraction of cells")
  }
  plot.list[[i]]=y
}
do.call(grid.arrange, c(plot.list, ncol=col))
```